# Using a progress Bar while I load a webpage in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, html

I'm currently loading a webpage using a thread and I need a progress bar to display while the page loads up. Whats the best way to implement this? My code to load the webpage is this

```
private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                /**
                 * establish a URL connection
                 */

                URL updateURL = new URL("http://www.mtsu.edu/alertupdates/");
                URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();

                /**
                 * create an Input stream and buffered array to
                 * prepare for parsing.
                 */
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                /**
                 * read in the html and parse it to bytes.
                 */

                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }

                /**
                 *  Convert the Bytes read to a String. 
                 */

                html = new String(baf.toByteArray());
                int position = html.indexOf("<h1>");
                int position2 = html.indexOf("<!--",position);
                html = html.substring(position, position2);
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
    };
```

Here is my attempt at Using AsyncTask and the entire code of my project.

```
package com.MTSUAndroid;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import java.lang.String;
import android.content.Context;

public class Alerts extends Activity {
    /**
     * private variables to hold the html strings for parsing.
     */
    private String html = "";
    private Handler mHandler;
    private TextView text1;
    private TextView timestamp;
    private Button home;
    private Button refresh;
    private ProgressDialog myProgress;
    private int myProgressStatus = 0;

    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();


    /**
     * overriding on create with a new handler for threading
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alerts);
        initialControls();
        //mHandler = new Handler();
        //checkUpdate.start();
   }

   public void connectivityMessage(String msg){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.setText(msg);
        toast.show();
   }

    /**
     * InitialControls function to set up all the initial controls for the GUI
     * Such as buttons, etc...
     */
    private void initialControls(){
    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_button);
    //myProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        /**
         * TimeStamp for the alerts refresh button
         */
    timestamp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timestamp); 
    refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);

    /**
     * implementing the refresh button/loading the website
     */

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                /**
                 * establish a URL connection
                 */
                URL updateURL = new URL("http://www.mtsu.edu/alertupdates/");
                URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();

                /**
                 * create an Input stream and buffered array to
                 * prepare for parsing.
                 */

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                /**
                 * read in the html and parse it to bytes.
                 */

                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }

                /**
                 *  Convert the Bytes read to a String. 
                 */

                html = new String(baf.toByteArray());
                int position = html.indexOf("<h1>");
                int position2 = html.indexOf("<!--",position);
                html = html.substring(position, position2);
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);

                /**
                 * using calendar class for the refresh button
                 */

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int years = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int months = 1 + c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                try{
                    if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                    {
                        String AM = "";
                        AM = "AM";
                        if (hours == 0)
                        {
                            hours = 12;
                        }
                        timestamp.setText("Refreshed on " + days + "-"
                        + months + "-" + years + " " +  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + AM);
                        timestamp.setTextSize(17f);
                        timestamp.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String PM = "";
                        PM = "PM";
                        timestamp.setText("Refreshed on " + days + "-"
                        + months + "-" + years + " " +  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + PM);
                        timestamp.setTextSize(17f);
                        timestamp.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){}       
            }

            /**
             * Catch exception E to catch all errors.
             */
            catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    );}

    /**
     * creating a new thread to run the URL.
     */
    private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                /**
                 * establish a URL connection
                 */

                URL updateURL = new URL("http://www.mtsu.edu/alertupdates/");
                URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();

                /**
                 * create an Input stream and buffered array to
                 * prepare for parsing.
                 */
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                /**
                 * read in the html and parse it to bytes.
                 */

                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }

                /**
                 *  Convert the Bytes read to a String. 
                 */

                html = new String(baf.toByteArray());
                int position = html.indexOf("<h1>");
                int position2 = html.indexOf("<!--",position);
                html = html.substring(position, position2);
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
    };

    /**
     * set the textView to the freshly parsed html for viewing
     */

    private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
        }
    };

    public class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        ProgressDialog progress;
        public myTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
            this.progress = progress;   
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Alerts.this, "Loading data..", "Please Wait");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                /**
                 * establish a URL connection
                 */

                URL updateURL = new URL("http://www.mtsu.edu/alertupdates/");
                URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();

                /**
                 * create an Input stream and buffered array to
                 * prepare for parsing.
                 */
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                /**
                 * read in the html and parse it to bytes.
                 */

                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }

                /**
                 *  Convert the Bytes read to a String. 
                 */

                html = new String(baf.toByteArray());
                int position = html.indexOf("<h1>");
                int position2 = html.indexOf("<!--",position);
                html = html.substring(position, position2);
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);
            } catch (Exception e){}
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An AsyncTask will help handle progress for you. Read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I've looked through AsyncTasks and I'm confused how I'm supposed to use it to display a progress bar?

Comment: The doInBackground method is like your run method in the Thread. Call publishProgress method within the doInBackground method to make progress updates. Another choice is just having an indeterminate progress meter. A thorough read of the link I posted would give you this information.

Comment: well I did read through it and I've gotten it to work except for the fact now that the progressBar does not disappear when the webPage is loaded. I tried to implement the onPostExecute but it didn't work..

Comment: Have you tried dismissing the progressbar? And exactly how is onPostExecute not working?

Comment: well my code in doInBackground looks like it never gets run...? I just copy pasted the code to load the webpage in there. And then it looks like onPostExecute NEVER gets executed it looks like.

Comment: The way I have it setup now. I have my onCreate that just sets the view, and then this AsyncTask.

Comment: @cj1098 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1705/discussion-between-probablykevin-and-cj1098)

Comment: I don't see you calling AsyncTask.execute()

Comment: That was a major problem, yes xD